# How to load images faster from Azure Blob?

Tags: opencv, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I've been trying to upload some images to azure blob and then using **ImageReader** in **Azure ML studio** to read them from the blob. The problem is that ImageReader takes a lot of time to load images and I need it in real time. 
I also tried making a **csv** of **4 images (four rows)** containing 800x600 pixels as columns **(500,000 cols. approx)** and tried simple **Reader**. Reader took **31 mins** to read the file from the blob.
I want to know the alternate methods of loading and reading images in Azure ML studio. If anyone know any other method or can share a helpful and relevant link.
Please share if i can speed up ImageReader by any means.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Azure CDN http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cdn/ , after which the blobs will get an alternative url. My blob downloads became about 4 times faster after switching.

Comment: I can't integrate my blob with cdn. Can you provide an example?